# how to write .ksh file as production

Tags: jvm, sh, jndi, ksh

I have written below .ksh file to execute the main class from EAR in WebSphere server using putty.

```
#!/bin/ksh
############################################################################
#
#
#
# Written By: xyz
#
# Sep 23, 2017
#
#
#
#
#
############################################################################

print " Process started"


java -cp \ 
"/appl/was/profiles/node/installedApps/cab/abcEar.ear/abcWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/*" \
    com.batch.FirtTool

print "Process End"
```

I am able to execute main class, but database connection is not happening properly. I am using hibernate JNDI stuff for connection.

If I am removing JNDI and directly I am using data source then my program is working properly.

But I need JNDI in my application.

Can you please help on this.

hibernate file like.

```
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property
    name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property
    name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/xyz</property>
```

With JNDI its not working, But We will use below direct property, Then its working .

```
<property name="connection.url">xyz</property>
<property name="connection.username">xyz</property>
<property name="connection.password">xyz</property>
```

Comment: Hi, Please any one help on this topic.

Comment: It is not related to ksh / shell script. It should be related to j2ee and how to get JNDI resources from J2EE Server for standalone application. Indeed, what is your purpose to execute a Main class located in AppServer standalone?

Comment: Its main class which will execute  some job via control-m daily basis.

Comment: You may look into [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074186/jndi/j2ee-or-j2se--jndi-works-with-both.html) or I suggest your script to call web service and invoke some services in J2EE server.